# AWS PublishVersion together with Serverless

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-cli, serverless-framework, aws-serverless

I have a pretty big project that I use Serverless Framework to deploy to AWS (a few lambdas together at a time) using Windows Terminal.

I would do:

```
serverless deploy -s integration
```

and it will take all of my lambdas and deploy them. My problem is that I need to use the versioning of AWS, and I don't know how to do it.

After I do the serverless deploy, do I need to open the AWS CLI console and run something like this for each lambda that I already deployed using serverless?

```
version=$(aws lambda publish-version --function-name test_lambda --description "updated via cli" --region eu-west-1| jq '.Version')
```

I'm just confused on how to combine the 2 ways of deploying lambdas.

Answer (score 0):

by default, all functions deployed with Serverless Framework are versioned. You can also disable it or turn it on explicitly by setting:

```
provider:
  versionFunctions: true (or false to turn it off)
```

Please keep in mind that the old versions are not removed automatically, so if you want to keep e.g. only a few previously deployed versions, you might need to use a plugin as https://github.com/claygregory/serverless-prune-plugin